# Reply URL in Azure AD Application with OpenIDConnect

Tags: asp.net, azure, openid-connect, azure-active-directory

I'm using Azure AD with OpenIdConnect and one Reply URL website, but I need connect by LocalHost for test and implement other function.

How can I have more then one Reply URL using UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication and without lost access in both.

My application is configured with Asp.Net Web.Forms (Visual Studio 2015).

Tks.

Vilela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's works but I needed implement others code, for example:

```
RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                    {
                        // This ensures that the address used for sign in and sign out is picked up dynamically from the request
                        // this allows you to deploy your app (to Azure Web Sites, for example)without having to change settings
                        // Remember that the base URL of the address used here must be provisioned in Azure AD beforehand.
                        string appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase;
                        context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = appBaseUrl;
                        context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = appBaseUrl;
                        return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
```

But, I'm have problem with multi tenants. Others users are authentication in my tenants. It is my problems or Azure problems?

Tks,
Vilela

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to change the **Reply URL** dynamiclly using the `RedirectToIdentityProvider`. You can refer the code sample below:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
           new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
           {
               ClientId = clientId,
               Authority = authority,
               PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
               RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
               Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
               {
                   AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                   {
                       context.HandleResponse();
                       context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                       return Task.FromResult(0);
                   },
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider=(context)=>
                    {
                        context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "";
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
               }
           });
```

However, if the application was already deployed to the web server, change the redirect URL to localhost may not work as you expected since there are two different application server for the web app running.

Comment: What this would mean is that you would set the redirect URI manually to the request URI? Sounds like the only way..

Comment: Thank you your return, but I'm not understand why change the redirect URL in Azure AD. It isn't automatic?

Comment: It is different between the redirect URL which you register for the app on  Azure portal and the redirect URL you passed in the request. The Azure ad will verify the passed redirect URL based on the value register on the portal. And if the value is verified then the Azure AD would return this URL to the client. Please feel free to let me if the issue is not resolved.

Comment: @Vilela If the reply resolve the issue please mark it as answer so that other communities who have the same issue could recognize the answer easily.